# Can jQuery be used to select elements from a returned string html?

Tags: jquery

For the following jQuery code:

```
$("#select").change(function() {
    $("#output").load("/output/", {}, function(data) {
        // I want to extract the value of an element in data
    }); 
});
```

The content of `data` is:

```
<div>
  Something
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="ajax-output" value="100" />
```

I want to get the value `ajax-output` from the `data` output. How can I do that using jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get it *directly*, since it's at the root, you need [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
$(data).filter("input[name='ajax-output']").val();
```

Or get it from the one you just inserted (via the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) call itself) using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).find("input[name='ajax-output']").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put an invisible div inside the page with the id "invisibleDiv". Then by the following code, you should be able to get the value of ajax-output:

```
$("#invisibleDiv").append(data);
var data = $("#invisibleDiv").find("input[name='ajax-output']").val();
```

Comment: You can actually skip the first step -- if you create a jQuery object and pass it HTML instead of a selector, it will create the hidden div on-the-fly and return a jQuery object pointing to that hidden div.