# select elements from a specified html string

Tags: jquery

All, Say you have a Html string like below. I want to select all the `li` element from it, and append them to a `ul`.

```
var sHtml="<li>..</li><li>..</li><li>..</li><li>..</li><span>xxx</span>";
$("#myUl").append($("li",$(sHtml)));
```

But this code doesn't work . Is there any way to make it using jquery?

Comment: All, find answer in SO.  Please review it . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660742/can-jquery-be-used-to-select-elements-from-a-returned-string-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var sHtml="<li>..</li><li>..</li><li>..</li><li>..</li><span>xxx</span>";
$(sHtml).not('span').appendTo("#myUl");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PsPT8/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var sHtml="<li>..</li><li>..</li><li>..</li><li>..</li><span>xxx</span>";
var htm = $(sHtml);
$("#myUl").append(htm).find("span").remove();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/apsBP/)

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is overwriting part of your current page with html from maybe a page returned by an AJAX call, then give the `<ul>` an `id` and do something like

```
$("#myliID").html($(returnedPage).find("#myliID").html());
```